# Need Remmina desktop older version 0.9.99.1

Tags: remote-desktop, clipboard, rdp, remmina

Remmina was working fine with 0.9.99.1 untill I did experiment with new ppa  and updated to 1.x version. 
Now I am not able to use clipboard and shared folder.
I added ppa from
https://launchpad.net/~9v-shaun-42/+archive/ubuntu/freerdp
While installing it is installing Remmina 1.0.1-rcgit.1 not 1.0.0 as given in software center.

When I am removing above ppa and Remmina and trying to install again I am getting dependency error. I tried uninstalling Remmina and deleting folder .remmina from home folder but it won't work.

For alternative, I installed KRDC but on clicking new connection nothing happening.

I badly need to have a remote desktop with shared folder (If possible with clipboard).
Anyway to downgrade Remmina or workable other alternative like KRDC.

Strange that, Remmina was already updated to 1.0.0 in 2012, but I installed it fresh on Ubuntu 14.04 few day ago only and at that time it took 0.9.99.1  version only.